How to resolve error: Could not initialize platform for 'dev': Access Denied in AWS Amplify
I cloned a repo to follow through on a tutorial. The Github repo has amplify folder already, meaning the original developer had already initialized amplify in the project. How do I successfully run amplify init? Because whenever I run the code I will get this error below:

$ amplify init
Note: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory
? Do you want to use an existing environment? Yes
? Choose the environment you would like to use: dev
Using default provider  awscloudformation
✖ Initializing your environment: dev
✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
 Could not initialize platform for 'dev': Access Denied

Thanks for your help.

similar question

Based on the error you are getting I have to ask. Are you sure you are in the root directory of the cloned repo. Sometimes it's easy to accidently navigate to the directory where your frontend is .ie React-Native, Next js etc.
I believe the command you're looking for is amplify pull. If there is already an amplify directory in your root directory, running amplify init could cause you to run into some issues.
In your root directory.
amplify pull

Also, make sure you have all the proper dependencies installed for the resources in Amplify. Check the package.json for dependencies that may need to be installed. Below is an example.
An example for a lambda function with dependencies.
cd amplify/backend/function/<function_name>/src

run:
npm install

Hope this helps.

In my case, the error occurred because I manually set up the files in the .aws folder to create a new profile. After running 'amplify pull,' it triggered the prompt: 'Select the authentication method you want to use: AWS profile,' and then I selected the newly created profile. This solved my authentication error.
